# Resizing a sprite with Pygame Zero

Tags: image-resizing, resize-image, pgzero

I am making a space invaders game using pgzrun and I am trying to resize a sprite I have.

I tried to research how to do it and I was not able to find a command. There is a command that does it in pygame but I was wondering if there is one for pygame zero.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Pygame Zero Helper](https://www.aposteriori.com.sg/pygame-zero-helper/). You have to download the file and add pgzhelper.py to the folder where your Python script resides.

You have to import pgzhelper:

```py
import pgzrun
from pgzhelper import *
```

Now you can do all sorts of additional stuff, e.g. scaling the sprite:

```py
alien = Actor('alien')
alien.scale = 0.5  # Half size
alien.scale = 2    # Double size
```

Answer (score 0):

Google brings myself and students here often. Workaround we implement is as follows:

```py
Actor._surf = pygame.transform.scale(Actor._surf, (width, height))
```